# using jQuery outside of $(document).ready()

Tags: jquery

I have created a function outside of `$(document).ready()`, but am still using jQuery inside of it. For example:

```
testFunction(){
  $('#test').hide();
  alert('test');
}
```

When I call `testFunction()` after the page has completely loaded, #test is not hidden but I do see the alert.

What must I do in order to use jQuery inside of this function? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Good to understand there are no restrictions for working outside `$(document).ready()`.

Here's why it's not working: I am not calling `testFunction()`, I am calling `parent.testFunction()` from an iframe and #test is in the parent frame. So... I guess I cannot use '#test' as a selector. What should I be using?

Comment: Does it work if you call it in $(document).ready() ?

Comment: It should work -- there is no restriction or additional work to use jquery outside $(document).ready().  Can we see your mark up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use '`#test`' as a selector, you just need to give [jQuery some context](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext), as it always assumes you're talking about an ID in the current document, not the parent:

```
// Selects the test element from the parent
var test = $('#test', parent)
```

**EDIT**
What context is jQuery being loaded from? The IFrame or the parent window? This can make a big difference.

I'd use an `alert()` to test if anything is found with jQuery. Call the `alert()` with the jQuery object as an argument.

```
alert($('#test'));
// or
alert($('#test').get(0));
// also try
alert(document.getElementById('test'));
```

If the last one doesn't work (it should alert 'HTMLElement', depending on the browser) then jQuery is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kinda old thread but here's another solution. Might help others :D .
    `jQuery('#test').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

Is there an element with an ID of test in the page?

Is JQuery loaded?

If you have added #test after loading the DOM, you will need to do some jiggling to rebind the elements to the DOM jQuery is using. That may be your issue.